# Dataframe append and drop_duplicates problem

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stock, data-stream

So, I have a dummy df like this and save it into csv:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

old_data = """date,time,open,high,low,close,volume
2021-05-06,04:08:00,9150090.0,9150090.0,9125001.0,9130000.0,9.015642
2021-05-06,04:09:00,9140000.0,9145000.0,9125012.0,9134068.0,3.121043
2021-05-06,04:10:00,9133882.0,9133882.0,9125002.0,9132999.0,5.536345
2021-05-06,04:11:00,9132999.0,9135013.0,9131000.0,9132999.0,5.880620"""

new_data = """timestamp,open,high,low,close,volume
1620274080000,9150090.0,9150090.0,9125001.0,9130000.0,9.015641820000004
1620274140000,9140000.0,9145000.0,9125012.0,9134068.0,3.121042509999999
1620274200000,9133882.0,9133882.0,9125002.0,9132999.0,5.5363449
1620274260000,9132999.0,9135013.0,9131000.0,9132999.0,5.88062024"""
```

I try to check if there is duplicated data between df_old and df_new and if any I drop it:

```
raw = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(new_data), encoding='UTF-8')

stream = pd.DataFrame(raw, columns=['timestamp', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'])
stream['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(stream['timestamp'], unit='ms')
stream['date'] = pd.to_datetime(stream['timestamp']).dt.date
stream['time'] = pd.to_datetime(stream['timestamp']).dt.time
stream = stream[['date', 'time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']]

for dif_date in stream.date.unique():
    grouped = stream.groupby(stream.date)
    df_new = grouped.get_group(dif_date)
    df_old = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(old_data), encoding='UTF-8')

df_stream = df_old.append(df_new).reset_index(drop=True)
df_stream = df_stream.drop_duplicates(subset=['time'])
print(df_stream)

>    date        time      open       high       low        close      volume
> 0  2021-05-06  04:08:00  9150090.0  9150090.0  9125001.0  9130000.0  9.015642
> 1  2021-05-06  04:09:00  9140000.0  9145000.0  9125012.0  9134068.0  3.121043
> 2  2021-05-06  04:10:00  9133882.0  9133882.0  9125002.0  9132999.0  5.536345
> 3  2021-05-06  04:11:00  9132999.0  9135013.0  9131000.0  9132999.0  5.880620
> 4  2021-05-06  04:08:00  9150090.0  9150090.0  9125001.0  9130000.0  9.015642
> 5  2021-05-06  04:09:00  9140000.0  9145000.0  9125012.0  9134068.0  3.121043
> 6  2021-05-06  04:10:00  9133882.0  9133882.0  9125002.0  9132999.0  5.536345
> 7  2021-05-06  04:11:00  9132999.0  9135013.0  9131000.0  9132999.0  5.880620
```

but the result still returned duplicated value, how to resolve this issue or to reorder it?
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1vMx9hXKcbz8SDawTnHbzpV6JiRZsEuVP?usp=sharing
thanks before

Comment: `df_old`'s time column is of type `<class 'str'>`, while `df_new`'s time column is of type `<class 'datetime.time'>` hence they are unequal and not dropped. `print(df_stream.time.apply(type))`

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't aware of the column type, it's resolved now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type along the time column is not constant therefore python is not able to tell the rows are equal.

For instance if you run:

```
df_stream.time.loc[0] == df_stream.time.loc[4]
```

You'll get False because the left hand side is a string and the right hand side is a datetime.time object.

You should force a type on the column 'time' with astype()

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't aware of the column type, it's resolved now